# best way for dividing dynamic(php) content from static content(html) for web design?

Tags: php, html, web-deployment, separation-of-concerns

Until this day I have been using notepad++ for website developing. my codes are like:

```
... 
<div><?php
$han=mysql_query("Blah blah ...");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($han);
// and so many codes to process text ..
echo $something;
?></div>
...
```

But maintenance of this kind of code is really hard. Now I see that everything is changing on webdesign. Everybody is going to make their websites responsive. I wish I could change my html code without seeing dynamic codes.

for example think I have have html file like this(static.html):

```
<div>#{content_here}</div>
```

and also a separate php file like this:

```
<?
$static_content=file_get_contents("static.html");
$han=mysql_query("Blah blah ...");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($han);
// and so many codes to process text ..
$content_here=$something;
echo str_replace("#{content_here}",$content_here,$static_content);
?>
```

This  way I can separate static content from dynamic content. But this is all my innovation. And every time I invent something then I find that there is even a better and more extensive thing already invented.

So is there already IDEs that support this kind of web development? possibly get contents generated by php in json format and then blend it with Html content.

Comment: Well, first never go just with what you find, you need to understand what are your needs ! I also use mix of static and dynamic content on my development, but I try to use my dynamic programming accessible by any kind of static data, so I have no worry about changing design in future !

Comment: Pretty much any php framework written in the last 10 years will have some way of doing this. There are also numerous standalone templating engines (eg twig, smarty), but the templating engine is not really the important part, its the separation of display and business logic, usually done nowadays via some take on MVC. Google laravel, symfony, slimphp or fatfreephp for a decent starting point

Comment: Also in regards to `now i see that everything is changing`, again you are somewhat behind the curve - client side rendering (angualrjs, vuejs) is the current upward trend

Comment: thanks for all useful comments, I think I should start with learning  laravel.

Comment: oh my gods. no, you should indeed not start with that. you should start by catching up on the loads of good practices that exist with php, the first being: how can you not have realized that mysql_* extension is deprecated, and that better more secure options have existed for [*years*](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php). Using a framework while having no cue about actual programming will not help you.

Comment: It's 10 years that I have been working in this area. I have almost done everything with my limited knowledge. I am good in programming But I have no experience in IDEs.